# how to create customized Wordpress docker image and remove default plugins and themes from official docker image

Tags: wordpress, docker, plugins, themes

you can use wp cli to do it in dokcer container instance launching.

1. We need add shell script in a official image file in /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh. So use command 'docker cp' copy the file to local path.
2. edit local file: find the line(at 67):

   ```
    echo >&2 "Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to $PWD"
   ```
3. add below shell script after that line.

   ```
    curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
    php wp-cli.phar --info
    chmod +x wp-cli.phar
    mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
    wp --info
    wp plugin list --allow-root
    wp plugin delete hello --allow-root
    wp plugin delete akismet --allow-root
    wp theme list --allow-root
    wp theme delete twentynineteen --allow-root
    wp theme delete twentytwenty --allow-root
    wp theme delete twentytwentyone --allow-root
   ```
4. Add below lines in your Dockerfile

   ```
    FROM wordpress:latest

    ADD ./wp-content /var/www/html/wp-content
    ADD ./wp-config.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php
    ADD ./vendor /var/www/html/vendor
    ADD ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

    WORKDIR /var/www/html
    EXPOSE 80
    CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
   ```

Comment: I looked for something like that. But somehow it did not work for me.